# How can I lookup error messages for an AWS SES email?

Tags: amazon-web-services, email

I am using AWS's SES to send emails. I am trying to use the template feature and don't receive any errors in my response, just a `MessageId`.

The problem is, the emails don't send when I have my "`HtmlPart`" template, but when I remove/simplify the "`HtmlPart`" to just a basic div, then it works.

How can I troubleshoot this, or is there some reason SES would reject an HTML email?

Should I not be including things like `<!doctype>`, etc. in this template?

I can't find anywhere to look up errors for a given `MessageId` in AWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an option in the depths of AWS's documentation:

`aws ses test-render-template --template-name "template-name" --template-data '{"key":"value"}'`

This will show the error messages which aren't displayed when the email is sent.

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ses/test-render-template.html

Comment: @d. Can you add a link to where you found this please? Very good information.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon forces you to use SNS to receive notifications of failed messages.

You can read more here
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ses-sendtemplatedemail-delivery-failure/